# complex string substitution

Tags: regex, sed

The aim of this question is to replace the /PageLabels code ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF17.html#PDF17-examples) ) in a pdf file for another. We have to do this because there is a bug in the program wich print the pdf (we can't change the program). By hand takes a lot of time (we made 50 pdf files per hour).

However to be pragmatic, the example can be summarized as follows.

**Old /PageLabels code:** Located in a original file called a.pdf.

We use the grep function to get the incorrect */PageLabels code*:

```
grep -aPo '/PageLabels\K[^"]*>>]>>' a.pdf

<</Nums[0<</S/r/St 1>>6<</S/r/St 7>>10<</S/r/St 11>>12<</S/r/St 13>>14<</P(1-)/S/D/St 1>>20<</P(2-)/S/D/St 1>>28<</P(3-)/S/D/St 1>>80<</P(4-)/S/D/St 1>>116<</P(A-)/S/D/St 1>>132<</P(B-)/S/D/St 1>>134<</P(C-)/S/D/St 1>>138<</P(D-)/S/D/St 1>>148<</P(E-)/S/D/St 1>>168<</P(F-)/S/D/St 1>>176<</P(G-)/S/D/St 1>>182<</P(Glossary-)/S/D/St 1>>194<</P(Comments-)/S/D/St 1>>]>>
```

**New /PageLabels code** We want to substitute the "*Old /PageLabels code*" using the following. This is the result of another script which reevaluate the pdf and get the correct */PageLabel code*  of the pdf (tested and verifed manually).

```
<</Nums[0<</S/r/St 1>>12<</P(1-)/S/D/St 1>>17<</P(2-)/S/D/St 1>>32<</P(3-)/S/D/St 1>>98<</P(4-)/S/D/St 1>>130<</P(A-)/S/D/St 1>>153<</P(B-)/S/D/St 1>>154<</P(C-)/S/D/St 1>>158<</P(D-)/S/D/St 1>>187<</P(E-)/S/D/St 1>>230<</P(F-)/S/D/St 1>>242<</P(G-)/S/D/St 1>>247<</P(Glossary-)/S/D/St 1>>259<</P(Comments-)/S/D/St 1>>]>>
```

It will be saved in another file called b.pdf

We don't know how to write it using the **sed** function.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you simplify what's the rule for matching here ? Also add some details in question.

Comment: Thank you, for the feedback! just redited!

Comment: What's "chain" here? What **specifically** in that mess of PDF garbage are you trying to match on and replace?

Comment: It is quite difficult to explain the example but I tried again. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `replace` instead of `sed` or `regex`:

```
#! /bin/bash
old=$(grep -aPo '/PageLabels\K[^"]*>>]>>' a.pdf) ## Get Old /PageLabels code
new=$(/tmp/get_correct_code.sh )  ## Get New /PageLabels code
cat a.pdf |replace "$old" "$new" > new_a.pdf
```

From the man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
       The replace utility program changes strings in place in files or on the standard input.

       Invoke replace in one of the following ways:

          shell> replace from to [from to] ... -- file_name [file_name] ...
          shell> replace from to [from to] ... < file_name
```

**UPDATE** If you prefer to use `sed`, you could try it this way:

```
#! /bin/bash
old=$(grep -aPo '/PageLabels\K[^"]*>>]>>' a.pdf) ## Get Old /PageLabels code
new=$(/tmp/get_correct_code.sh )  ## Get New /PageLabels code

# To replace $old with $new, first you'd have to escape those characters like [, ], -
eold=$(echo $old | sed 's@\([][-]\)@\\\1@g')

# Then do the replace using sed
sed "s@$eold@$new@g" a.pdf > b.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However the condition is to use sed function.

Comment: Updated with `sed` approach.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!. Also I found same explanation here [link](http://backreference.org/2009/12/09/using-shell-variables-in-sed/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand specific information you are trying to replace from chain. However, as I break down the chain I see that variations as per below figure (Stack was going crazy trying to substitute all of the special characters, hence putting in as a picture)
[image: Old_new_Chain]

If I am assuming correctly, you want to change pagetags `1>>6` with `1>>12` and so on

If thats what you want , you can use following to replace old with new

`cat a.pdf |sed -e 's/1>>20/1>>98/' -e 's/1>>28/1>>130/'` and so on.
you can keep adding -e to the above as long as shell takes it [ it will depend on your *nix version].

Alternately, you will need to write a shell script to read each line and replace a particulate field based on certain logic. Assuming numbers in new_chain vary from old_chain by some K factor that can be formulated.

If you can post old / new data as per below, and let me know if there is any  standard variation between old and new I can help further.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer and your time. Unfortunately the solution that you propose is not valid. The assumption is wrong; we want to substitute the complete string. As you can see the New_Chain is almost equal to the Old_Chain. However in other cases Old_Chain and New_Chain are not even similar. This New_Chain reorder the numeration in the /PageLabels inside a pdf.

Comment: I have to explain that if you want to substitute the / PageLabels code in a pdf document, the number of new bytes added must be exactly the same as the oldest bytes. In other words New_Chain must have the same size as Old_Chain.Lucky us, the number of old bytes are always bigger than new ones (let’s obvious the why question). So we added 0x20 (ASCII charater : space) to complete the correct size in the New_Chain